# Javascript: dynamically creating and accessing an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having no luck creating and accessing an array of objects.  I'm trying to draw 10 random rectangles on a canvas and store their X,Y, Width and Height in an array to access later.

```
var square =  {cX : 0,  cY : 0,  W : 200,  H : 100}
var squares = [];  
var squaresToMake = 10;

for ( var loopy = 0; loopy < squaresToMake; loopy++ ) {
 square.cX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
 square.cY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
 square.W = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
 square.H = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
 squares.push(square);
}

var arrayLength = squares.length;
for (var loopy = 0; loopy < arrayLength; loopy++) {
 ctx.rect(squares[loopy].cX, squares[loopy].cY, squares[loopy].W, squares[loopy].H);
 ctx.fill();
}
```

The result I'm getting is the squares array is full of 10 objects that all have the same values: the last values that were generated from loop that assigns random numbers.  Please advise me what I'm doing wrong!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same object (square) ten times, because objects are stored/passed by reference. Every time you put new values into 'square' you are just updating the same object. Move "var square" into the loop, so you create a new square each cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same object to the array. Bring the `square` object inside the for loop so that new one get created on each iteration. Currently, you will only see the 10 elements that points to same reference, which contains an square object with lastly added values.

```
var squares = [];  
var squaresToMake = 10;

for ( var loopy = 0; loopy < squaresToMake; loopy++ ) {
 var square =  {cX : 0,  cY : 0,  W : 200,  H : 100}
 square.cX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
 square.cY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
 square.W = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
 square.H = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
 squares.push(square);
}

var arrayLength = squares.length;
for (var loopy = 0; loopy < arrayLength; loopy++) {
 ctx.rect(squares[loopy].cX, squares[loopy].cY, squares[loopy].W, squares[loopy].H);
 ctx.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your requirements can be met like this. sometimes, not defining extra variables make the code less error prone.

```
var squares = [];
var squaresToMake = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < squaresToMake; i++) {
  squares.push({
    cX: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
    cY: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
    W: Math.floor(Math.random() * 200),
    H: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
  });
}

squares.forEach(function(sq) {
  ctx.rect(sq.cX, sq.cY, sq.W, sq.H);
  ctx.fill();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more ES6 approach for the generation of the values:

```js
var squares = [];  
var keys = ['cX', 'cY', 'W', 'H']
var squaresToMake = 10;

const newValue = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().getMilliseconds())
const newSquare = () => keys.reduce((r,c) => Object.assign({[c]: newValue() }, r), {})

Array.from(new Array(squaresToMake), (x) => squares.push(newSquare()) )
console.log(squares)
```